# Why root symbol does not works in hyper link when returned by an expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Just a thought came in mind.
Why the first of these two tags does not work in asp.net?

To me both are string values whose final value is same. Which is value of attribute href of hyperlink.

Please make me understand it.

```
<a href="@(string.Format("~/Test/Index"))">Test</a>
<a href="~/Test/Index">Test</a>
```

Note: I am not looking for solution to it. Only want to understand what's logically difference between these two case.

Comment: You don't need to add Controller postfix

Comment: Updated question. That was only a example value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me both are string values whose final value is same

Not really. Consider first if you just had a plain non-razor HTML form such as if you'd hard-coded the beginning of the path:

```
<a href="/SomeProject/Test/Index">Test</a>
```

Now, here "/SomeProject/Test/Index" **is not** a string. It's an attribute value in HTML. HTML has no concept of "string". Sure it happens to use the same delimiter as C# does for string, but this isn't C# here.

With Razor we have a few means to indicate we want something done by Razor to the otherwise plain HTML.

`@` is one of them, indicating that we want a C# expression evaluated and the result (if not void) output. And the result of `(string.Format("~/Test/Index"))` is `~/Test/Index` so that is output.

`~/` is, in certain contexts, another one, indicating that it should be replaced with the value of evaluating `Href("~/")` or `Url.Content("~/")`, which would be something like `/` or `/SomeProject/` or whatever. It's not so much a string as something more like a keyword.

If you have an expression returning a string, you can still use strings similarly with:

```
<a href="@Href(string.Format("~/Test/Index"))">Test</a>
```

Which incidentally, was the only way this could be done in Razor 1.0. The direct parsing of `"~/…` was added as a convenience and it is indeed convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what [`string.Format(string format, params Object[] args)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) does. It will only replace specified placeholders `{0}`, `{1}`, etc with provided paramters. Take a look at the docs in the link provided for more info.

In short it doesn't do any automatic replacement of environment variables or any other substitutions not already covered by the placeholders.

`String.Format` sits in the `System` namespace, therefore I wouldn't expect it to know anything about web sites, file systems or anything more complicated than simple placeholder substitution and formatting.

You should be using `Url.Action` i.e.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("~/Test/Index")">Test</a>
```

or even easier

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Index", "Test")
```

Also note that in ASP.Net MVC you don't use the full controller name, only the prefix i.e. `Test` instead of `TestController`

Comment: Thanks, I understand these. I only want to know why it does not works or what's diff. Updated question.

Comment: @Satyajit Updated my answer with clarification of string.Format's limitations